# prevent keyboard from automatically switching to text mode

Tags: android

I have an edit text which accepts both text and numeric values.
I have to format it with appending space after every 4 characters.
here are the steps to replicate the issue
1. tap on the edit text
2. select number mode on the keypad and keep entering numbers
3. the moment space is appended, the keyboard switches to text mode. how do I prevent it. Here is the code I tried

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {

             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
             {

             }

             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int count, int after)
             {

             }

             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int before, int count)
             {


              String text = editText.getText().toString();
          textlength = editText.getText().length();

          if(text.endsWith(" "))          
              return;

          if(textlength == 5 || textlength == 10 || textlength == 20)
          {
            editText.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length()-1, " ").toString());
              editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
          }

             }});

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is in your program
a) Check if space character is received. If yes
b) Switch to numeric keypad using the function  setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)

Hopefully this will solve the issue. But you will need to be monitoring each character input by user.